# Select only specific patterns from a SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to select only a specific pattern from a SQL column.  Its an XML type column, however its not formatted as XML.  Here's an example of what might be contained in the field for one record:

```
taSopDistribution
i   3
s   W-13-I73516502
:d:
i   7
:d:
:d:
s   60-99-9999-99-20950-00
m   0
m   5.8800
s   W-13
:d:
:d:
:d:
:d:
:d:
:d:
s   60-99-9999-00-60950-00
```

I need to be able to query this field and select only the pieces of data that follow this pattern: `##-##-####-##-#####-##`, and there will be multiple matches.

For example, I need a query that returns the following values from the example data field above:

```
60-99-9999-99-20950-00
60-99-9999-00-60950-00
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!  FYI, I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Not to take away from the question, but the real question here should be, why in the world do you have tables like this? You shouldn't store multiple meanings of data in the same column.

Comment: I should clarify, this is an example of the data contained in one field for a single record.  Its essentially a data dump of each record into this one XML field.

Comment: I'm confused. How can a field of type XML not be formatted as XML?

Answer (score 0):

This can do the trick :

```
SELECT substring(taSopDistribution,5,len(taSopDistribution)-5)
FROM Table1
WHERE taSopDistribution
LIKE '%-__-____-__-_____-__'
```

**Results**:

```
|              COLUMN_0 |
|-----------------------|
| 60-99-9999-99-20950-0 |
| 60-99-9999-00-60950-0 |
```

See **[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f62c/10/0)**